# Is there a way of obtaining a list of guest virtuals running on an esx host before its failure?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

ESXi 4 host running a resource pool had a power failure. Is there a way to obtain a list of the guest VMs running on the host before the failure?

Running in a vSphere 5 environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have HA enabled, then you can look at the HA log and see the list of VMs that were started on other hosts. Absent that, the VMs on that host are probably the ones that aren't currently running. :)

Comment: HA was enabled, this might be the way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another "low tech" way of doing this would be to look at what VM folders exist on the datastore... if you're using shared storage. The process of elimination should allow you to determine what folders exist for VM's running on existing hosts and what folders exist for VM's not found on any running hosts.

Comment: Cheers! Good low tech backup way of grabbing them.